# Is there a vertical component equivalent of v-toolbar in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm looking to create a toolbar of buttons, and was wondering if there is a vertical component in Vuetify like v-toolbar? My current alternative solution is to vertically stack buttons in a div.

Comment: What about the `v-navigation-drawer` with `mini` prop?

Comment: @cmfc31 I attempted to use that component, but had issues with dynamic resizing with it in a parent container. Ended up using a div with custom styling